# Chain initialization without temporary pointers

Tags: c++, initialization

An object of class `A` is constructed from an object of class `B`, which is inherited by class `C`. How can I create an `A` object without temporary pointers to the `B` object?

```
B *my_b = new C();
A *my_a = new A( *my_b );
// but *my_b is only used here
```

Update: The constructor of `A` takes a `B` as the argument, not a `C`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to retain the object of type `B` **and** `class A` constructor copies the object and doesn't instead store a reference to it:

```
A* my_a = new A( B() );
```

otherwise you can't do anything much better than what you're doing already.

Comment: Note that the constructor of `A` needs to take the argument by const reference for this to work.

Comment: Okay, then make it `new A( C() )`.

Comment: This compiles in VC++ with a warning "nonstandard extension used - A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue" - looks like `A` should accept `const B&` for this to work on your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `new` unless you have a reason to.

```
A my_a = A( B() );
```

Or if there is a reason to `new` my_a:

```
A * my_a = new A( B() );
```